# Is there a unique accepted Lagrangian formulation of Nambu mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

In section 5 of their 2000 paper "[Nambu Mechanics in the Lagrangian Formalism](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1026421401600)", Ogawa & Sagae critique previous attempts by Bayen & Flato and by [Takhtajan](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02103278) to formulate the theory with a single Lagrangian, arguing instead that the proper generalization of Lagrangian classical mechanics is to introduce multiple Lagrangians, one for each of the Nambu Hamiltonians.

To what extent are these different approaches compatible?  Is one clearly better than the others, or is the issue still murky?